# How to find the route between two points/markers in Google Earth using KML? 

Tags: linux, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml, google-earth

Google Maps API has a `route` function to do the same. Couldn't find anything like that in Google Earth API.

- How to find the route/path between two points/markers in Google Earth?

This is to be done on Linux, so won't be able to integrate it with Javascript API of Google maps.

Comment: Why should Linux prevent you from using Javascript API of Google maps? It's not OS dependent, as far as I know. (I used Google maps API v3 on Ubuntu)

Comment: @nadirs no, I was talking about its integration with Earth. For that I'll need Earth's plugin. Isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [DirectionsAPI](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/). It's linked from the Javascript Maps API documentation but is a REST API and can return results in XML.

Just make sure to check the [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_12) to verify that your usage is allowed.

Comment: thanks for your answer. the Earth on Linux uses KML files. will the XML output help me with Earth on Linux?

Comment: You'll have to integrate the Directions API results manually into your kml files. Both are XML based however.

Comment: oh, that means, I'll have to run this API separately somewhere and then pick up its results and paste in the kml file? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: That is one possible solution. There are many possibilities and it depends on the specifics of your project. They are separate APIs, but could conceivably be used within the same project.

Comment: thanks for replying, but you said: `They are separate APIs,`. The one you linked here can be used only in the address bar of the web browser? Is it true? Is there any other way of using it? Please elaborate.